# Copy out parts of an EDL, calculate duration but loop fails

Tags: loops, vbscript, timecodes

I have a simply formatted text file (Edit Decision List) with rows of numbers followed by rows of properties (names etc.).
For each match, I am trying to make a list from the name string, followed by duration (difference between timestamps).

Resulting in:

> 12 - Tech Sexy - D Cebert - FFP170  Dur:00.38

So far I've

1. established a way for the user to define the source file on their desktop.
2. defined a way to sort the source timestamps (by timestamp that precedes the appropriate name line).
3. found a difference between the first 2 timestamps.

But my loop does not seem to work. I at least expect to see a list of durations for each matched timestamp line.

Script so far:

```
Option Explicit
'change system location to Germany, to simulate 24hour clock *no AM PM time
SetLocale "de-de"

Dim fso, oFile, y, re, prev, line, matches, time
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'get user to open file name
y = InputBox("name of file to save")

'next line opens a file with that name 
Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(y&".edl")

Do Until oFile.AtEndOfStream
    line = oFile.ReadLine
    'At this point the variable prev either is empty (during the first loop
    'cycle) or holds the content of the previous line.
    If Left(line, 21) = "*  FROM CLIP NAME:   " Then
        'Define search terms for each timecode element *this is not a result yet
        Dim re1
        re1 =".*?"  'Non-greedy match on filler
        Dim re2
        re2 ="((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)"  'HourMinuteSec 1
        Dim re3
        re3 =".*?"  'Non-greedy match on filler
        Dim re4
        re4 ="((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)"    'HourMinuteSec 2
        Dim re5
        re5 =".*?"  'Non-greedy match on filler
        Dim re6
        re6 ="((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)"    'HourMinuteSec 3
        Dim re7
        re7 =".*?"  'Non-greedy match on filler
        Dim re8
        re8 ="((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)"    'HourMinuteSec 4

        'add timecode search terms to a search pattern
        Dim r
        Set r = New RegExp
        r.Pattern = re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8
        r.IgnoreCase = True

        Dim m, timeDur, ts, Timeofday
        Set m = r.Execute(line)
        'loop through timecodes to find duration between first 2 entries
        If m.Item(0).SubMatches.Count > 0 Then
            Dim time1
            time1 = m.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0)
            Dim time2
            time2 = m.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(1)
            Dim time3
            time3 = m.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(2)
            Dim time4
            time4 = m.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(3)

            'find duration/difference between first 2 times, in seconds
            timeDur=datediff("s", time1, time2)
            'format result to a serial time format eg. 00:00:00
            ts = TimeSerial(0, 0, timeDur)
            'print duration result, will need to append track info and repeat. Then save to file
            MsgBox (ts)
        End If
        MsgBox (ts)
    End If
Loop
```

Source file:

```
* COMMENT:  CREATED BY GRASS VALLEY FOR EDIUS (CMX-3600) 
001  0000     A     C        00:00:04:23 00:00:42:04 00:00:00:00 00:00:37:06
* FROM CLIP NAME:  12 - Tech Sexy - D Cebert - FFP170
002  0000     A     C        00:00:20:01 00:00:31:23 00:01:29:24 00:01:41:21
* FROM CLIP NAME:  03 - Web Of Deceit (Main) - J Woodall - SFT164
003  0000     A     C        00:00:31:23 00:00:31:23 00:01:41:21 00:01:41:21
M2   0000        025.0              00:00:31:23
003  0000     A     D    025 00:00:31:09 00:00:54:12 00:01:41:21 00:02:04:24
* EFFECT NAME: CROSS DISSOLVE
* FROM CLIP NAME:  03 - Web Of Deceit (Main) - J Woodall - SFT164
* TO CLIP NAME:  03 - Web Of Deceit (Main) - J Woodall - SFT164
M2   0000        025.0              00:00:31:09
004  0000     A2    C        00:01:15:08 00:01:31:24 00:01:48:04 00:02:04:20
* FROM CLIP NAME:  12 - Environs A - T Juckes, S Kidd - SCDV354
005  0000     A2    C        00:00:11:12 00:00:30:05 00:02:06:24 00:02:25:17
* FROM CLIP NAME:  13 - Contagion (Main) - J Woodall - SFT164
006  0000     A2    C        00:00:06:13 00:00:56:09 00:02:27:04 00:03:17:00
* FROM CLIP NAME:  03 - Web Of Deceit (Main) - J Woodall - SFT164
007  0000     A2    C        00:00:56:09 00:00:56:09 00:03:17:00 00:03:17:00
M2   0000        025.0              00:00:56:09
007  0000     A2    D    025 00:00:55:08 00:01:54:03 00:03:17:00 00:04:15:20
* EFFECT NAME: CROSS DISSOLVE
* FROM CLIP NAME:  03 - Web Of Deceit (Main) - J Woodall - SFT164
* TO CLIP NAME:  03 - Web Of Deceit (Main) - J Woodall - SFT164
M2   0000        025.0              00:00:55:08
008  0000     A2    C        00:01:15:08 00:01:37:12 00:05:04:10 00:05:26:14
* FROM CLIP NAME:  12 - Environs A - T Juckes, S Kidd - SCDV354
009  0000     A2    C        00:00:00:00 00:00:26:19 00:06:00:08 00:06:27:02
* FROM CLIP NAME:  38 - Signs Of Pollution - W Plass - SCDV354
010  0000     A2    C        00:00:25:08 00:01:13:03 00:06:39:16 00:07:27:11
* FROM CLIP NAME:  38 - Signs Of Pollution - W Plass - SCDV354
011  0000     A2    C        00:01:13:03 00:01:13:03 00:07:27:11 00:07:27:11
M2   0000        025.0              00:01:13:03
011  0000     A2    D    025 00:01:48:22 00:02:04:09 00:07:27:11 00:07:42:23
* EFFECT NAME: CROSS DISSOLVE
* FROM CLIP NAME:  38 - Signs Of Pollution - W Plass - SCDV354
* TO CLIP NAME:  38 - Signs Of Pollution - W Plass - SCDV354
M2   0000        025.0              00:01:48:22
```

Comment: The format of our input data seems a little different from what you originally posted in a previous question, so instead of `Left(line, 21) = "*  FROM CLIP NAME:   "` you need `Left(line, 19) = "* FROM CLIP NAME:  "`. Also, please re-read my answer to your other question. You want to apply the regular expression to the *previous* line, *not* the one currently read. And again, some of the preceding lines do not contain timestamps, so you need to handle that, otherwise your code will error out.

Comment: The problem is that it does not error out. I just get an empty MsgBox, in this code and on the other question page. The loop does not seem to generate any matches nor can I return them as any kind of string.

Comment: Take one step after the other. First adjust the `If` condition as described in my comment above. Put a `WScript.Echo line` statement in the line below the `If` and you'll see that it displays those lines. Then execute your regular expression *not on those lines*, but on the lines *preceding* them. For that you need the code I outlined in my previous answer.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you for your patience. I really appreciate it.